# Date in directory name not recognized on windows

Tags: linux, date, unix, mkdir

I created a script to run on a linux system that creates a folder on a network drive with the current date and time in its name. However, windows interprets the folder name incorrectly. This only happens if I run these commands as a script, entering them in the terminal does the trick as expected. What am I doing wrong?

The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh
mynow="$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M)"
mkdir /SOMEDIRECTORY/TEST_$mynow
```

I run the script with: `sh myscript`

On windows this gives folders in the SOMEDIRECTORY directory with names like `TEST_2~1`, instead of `TEST_yyyymmdd_hhMM`

Comment: I noticed that listing the network direcory's contents from the linux sytem shows that "??" is added to the directory name.

Comment: Please do _not_ add additional information in comments. There is an `edit` link below your question. _Use it._